# How do i add another layer inside of filled rectangle using loop

Tags: c++

So i need to add other layer inside the box.The first layer of box is the letter "L". I have managed to make second layer of the box using letter "B". So i need to  make the third layer of letter "P" inside the letter "B" without ruining the first and second layer. This is what i managed to do so far

```
     cout<<"X = ";
     cin>>x;

      for(int a=0;a<x;a++)//Top Col
        {
            cout<< " L ";
        }

            cout<<endl;


        for(int b=0;b<x-2;b++) {
            cout<< " L ";

            for(int inside=1;inside<=x-2;inside++){
                cout<< " B ";

            }
                cout<< " L ";
                cout<<endl;
        }
        for(int a=0;a<x;a++)//Bottom Col
            {
            cout<< " L ";
            }

            cout<<endl;
```

My program looks like this :

```
X = 5

L L L L L 
L B B B L
L B B B L
L B B B L
L L L L L
```

I need to change the middle "B" to another letter, or letter "P" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already creating the grid using brute force you could just use the same technique you applied for the first and last rows to the middle one.

If you wanted to make this code more interesting you could use a 2d array. For example if you filled the 2d array with all L values and then had a for loop to fill in the other spots with B and P values. Include for loop limits set with something like x%2 and you will be able to customize your grid much more effectively.

For example:

```
    int x=getInput(); //number of columns and rows

char myArray[x][x];

for(int i = 0; i < x; i++j)
    for(int j = 0; j < x; j++)
        myArray[i][j] = 'L';

for(int i = (x % 2) -1; i < (x % 2) + 1; i++)
   for(int j = (x % 2) -1; i < (x % 2) + 1; i++)
      myArray[i][j] = 'B';

for(int i for(int i = x % 2; i < x % 2; i++)
   for(int j = (x % 2); i < x % 2; i++)
      myArray[i][j] = 'P';
```

Comment: My teacher said that I could not use array for this assignment. Can you explain what should i do with "the middle one" ? Should i add another loop?

Comment: I'm not completely sure of the purpose of this assignment but I suppose what I would do is add an if statement inside your double for loop and add a counter so that only the middle value is changed. Hope this is what you are looking for and good luck